# How to give an input to an application like XFLR5 through Matlab

Tags: matlab, xflr5

I am doing propeller performance analysis using MATLAB, for this I gather the required data, for example section properties, through [XFLR5](http://www.xflr5.com/xflr5.htm). I want to know how to run  XFLR5 through MATLAB so that every input I give to XFLR5 can be automatically given by MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something to do this a few years ago via XFOIL, the underlying engine for XFLR5. Check out [MatPerlXFOIL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpxfoil/). Note that I haven't used it in a *REALLY* long time and I haven't supported it for probably 2 years now. I wrote MPXF to give you lift, drag, moment, and pressure coefficients as a function of Reynolds number and angle of attack.

If you're using a Windows machine this probably won't work for you; the underlying Perl requires pseudottys to talk to XFOIL, which Windows does not support. You could probably pull it off using Cygwin, though.

EDIT: I looked at my documentation again. It's definitely doable via Cygwin, but overall the setup process takes a lot longer if you aren't on a *NIX-based system.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Dang khoa, I will try to do that with xfoil if I don't find a way to get it done with xflr5.